# Junit TestSuite with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot

I have a test suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        A.class,
        B.class
})
public class TestSuite {
}
```

A class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class A {
//nothing
}
```

B class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

@TestPropertySource(value = "classpath:testApplication.properties")
public class B {
//nothing
}
```

Now the problem is with `@TestPropertySource` the  `testApplication.properties` is located under the `test/java/testApplication.properties` and the `A` and `B` classes are under `test/java/com.example.MyApp`.
If I comment the line with the `@TestPropertySource` test suit runs ok but with it uncommented I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)

1. What is wrong with this setup?
2. Is it the localization of the `properties` file?
3. Shall I maybe use [@TestPropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) ?

EDIT
The caused by is:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [testApplication.properties] cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist

However why the location in `test/java/testApplication.properties` is not being found?

Comment: if u will use intellij insted of eclipse u will see the problem immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to solve the issue the problem seem that the `properties` file must be in `test/java/resources/testApplication.properties`. So the answer is put the properties file into `resources` directory.